# Show that a normed space is a Banach space

Tags: analysis

Let $\mathbb{C}$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$.
Let $\psi$ be a real-valued function satisfying $\psi(a+b) = \psi(a)+\psi(b)$ for all $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. Define:

$\sigma(x) = |\psi(x)|$ for any real number $x$.

I have already verified $\sigma$ is a norm on $\mathbb{R}$ and hence $(\mathbb{R}, \sigma)$ is well-defined as a normed space. I want to show it is a Banach space, that is every Cauchy sequence is convergent.

Although I know the definitions, I have no idea how to proceed. May I ask for any hints? Is my assertion that this normed space is Banach wrong in the first place? If yes, how should I disprove it?

Comment: This norm is less exotic than you might think; your conditions make $\psi$ a continuous solution to [Cauchy’s Functional Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_functional_equation), and hence $\psi(x)=kx$ for some constant $k$.

Comment: @TheoBendit Why is $\psi$ continuous?

Comment: It appears I mixed up sequential continuity for having a closed graph @azif00. It should be possible to show that $\psi$ is at least measurable, which also suffices. Or, since $\sigma$ is a norm on $\Bbb{R}$, it will automatically be $|\sigma(1)|$ times the usual norm.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Using that $|x| \leq \sigma(x)$ for each $x \in \Bbb R$, conclude that $(x_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $(\Bbb R,|\cdot|)$. Hence, it converges in $(\Bbb R,|\cdot|)$. In the same way, $(\psi(x_n))$ converges in $(\Bbb R,|\cdot|)$.

Below is the full solution.

> If $(x_n)$ converges to $L$ in $(\Bbb R,|\cdot|)$, then, by (ii), we have that $(\psi(x_n))$ converges to $\psi(L)$ in $(\Bbb R,|\cdot|)$. Hence, by (i), $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \psi(x_n-L) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \big( \psi(x_n)-\psi(L) \big) = 0,$$ and then $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sigma(x_n-L) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \big( |x_n-L| + |\psi(x_n-L)| \big) = 0.$$